# PHP regular expression - number (price) only

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to remove .00 from price field. I have price output like this:

```
127,000.00 €
```

My regex expression is:

```
 <?php  $site = get_field('price'); $site = preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $site ); $site = rtrim($site, ''); echo $site;?>
```

Result is:

```
12700000
```

It should be:

```
 127000
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: What if it's `127,000.50 €`?

Comment: `str_replace([',', '.00 €'], ['', ''], $site);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$amount =  "127,000.00 €";
$amount = explode(" ",$amount);
$amount =  $amount[0];
$amount = str_replace( ',', '', $amount );
echo (int) $amount ;
```

output: `127000`

Comment: Mmmm.. yeah... Almost... https://3v4l.org/jMZFt there are still cases that OP has not responded to, let's wait and see what he/she actually wants. Also just removing anything after a dot may not always be correct. Some countries has dot as thousands separators

Comment: @DanFromGermany updated the answer. @Andreas, initially I thought `"127,000.00 $"` is the final output and the OP has access to 127,000.00 that's why I did that.

Answer (score 1):

A better aproch with PHP 7+...

Ignoring the decimals:

```
$site = '127,000.00 €';
$site = (int) preg_replace('/\..*|\D/', NULL, $site);
echo $site;
// 127000
```

Rounding:

```
$site = '127,000.50 €';
$site = round(preg_replace('/[^\d.]/', NULL, $site));
echo $site;
// 127001
```

Answer (score 0):

`$amtstr = explode(' ', "127,000.00 €");
$value  = round(str_replace(',','',$amtstr[0])).' '.$amtstr[1];
echo $value;`

Hope this may help you